# How to translate Shortcuts name

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, translation

I translate title and description like that:

```
@available(iOS 16.0, macOS 13.0, watchOS 9.0, *) struct AddTask : AppIntent {
static var title: LocalizedStringResource = LocalizedStringResource("Add rope", table: "Localizable.strings.")
static var description = IntentDescription(LocalizedStringResource("Add task to the ropes app", table: "Localizable.strings."))
```

It translated inside Localizable.strings. But when I open them in shortcuts app I see untranslated text although My app works in Russian

(some text because I don't know how to move images)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your translation file have right targets[image]